# NodeJS - how to match one time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this HTTP nodeJS server, but when i visit the url it always output twice.

```
const https = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

https.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);

  try {
    var query =url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    if(query.id=='1') {
      console.log('OK matched');
    } else {
      console.log('No match');
    }

    res.end("req " + query.id);
  }catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}).listen(8000);
```

Now when i open http://localhost:8000?id=donot-match
then it prints two times:

```
No match
No match
```

When match found it still prints

```
OK matched
No match
```

How to make sure the action occurred only once? (on no Match i have to execute some exe which cant be twice executed and also same for match)

Comment: Do you really want to use the above routing strategy in your application?

Comment: Actually, i want username and password validation first and then the rest as it is. so in the GET url i want to have username/password once that is matched then the third parameter id should be allowed else not. or a .htpasswd like popup ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are hitting this in a browser, likely the browser is requesting the favicon, which doesn't match.

Comment: YES - Google chrome/Chromium i am using that url. i need to block the program favicon, but how do i know there is a request of favicon coming in my server?

Comment: @YumYumYum you need to handle those requests separately or just return a 404 in not a match.

Comment: OK - thank you sir.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17966435/ - Thank you this worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053829/nodejs-how-to-match-one-time